# Difference between $O(|V|+|E|)$ and $O(V+E)$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics

From CLRS:

> Given an adjacency-list representation of a multigraph $G = (V,E)$, describe an $O(V + E)$ time algorithm ...

I am struggling to understand what $O(V+E)$ means. Is it supposed to be $O(|V|+|E|)$, or maybe it's referring to the union of the two sets? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your first guess is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $O(V+E)$ just an abbreviation for $O(|V|+|E|)$. There is no possible confusion since, in this context, the operand of $O(\cdot)$ is supposed to be a function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, not a set.